# Chromedriver Manager download doesn't work after .exe conversion via PyInstaller

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I am using Selenium and Python to automate a task. When my program runs as myscript.py, it works seamlessly. I am converting myscript.py to myscript.exe using:

```
PyInstaller --onefile --windowed --icon="icon.ico" --add-data "icon.ico;." myscript.py
```

The resulting myscript.exe file does not work, giving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myscript.py", line 155, in <module>
File "myscipt.py", line 32, in main
File "webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 39, in install
File "webdriver_manager\core\manager.py", line 30, in _get_driver_path
File "webdriver_manager\core\download_manager.py", line 28, in download_file
File "webdriver_manager\core\http.py", line 35, in get
File "webdriver_manager\core\utils.py", line 289, in show_download_progress
File "tqdm\std.py", line 1109, in __init__
File "tqdm\std.py", line 1361, in refresh
File "tqdm\std.py", line 1509, in display
File "tqdm\std.py", line 350, in print_status
File "tqdm\std.py", line 343, in fp_write
File "tqdm\utils.py", line 89, in __getattr__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Line 32 in main is:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

I am probably missing something fundamental. Any help from the community is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that webdriver_manager uses tqdm to show a progress bar in the terminal during the `show_download_progress` function, however since you are using the `--windowed` option with `pyinstaller` your program isn't run with a terminal.  So when tqdm tries to show the progress bar there is nothing to write to, which is why it says `NoneType object has no attribute 'write'`.

This can be typically be solved by explicitly setting `stdout` and `stderr` to an object with a `write` method near the entrypoint to your application so they are set before any other code attempts to write to them.

For example:

```
import io
import sys

buffer = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = buffer
sys.stderr = buffer
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander! I just tried it out and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to disable **webdriver_manager** progressbar (keep other program messages), function `show_download_progress` has a config setting [here](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/blob/v3.8.5/webdriver_manager/core/config.py).

You can simply set `WDM_PROGRESS_BAR` environment variable to hide **webdriver_manager** messages from tqdm.

```
import os
os.environ["WDM_PROGRESS_BAR"] = "0"
```